# Python library 'nsetools' not working on linux

Tags: python

I have a small piece of python code on AWS linux.
Same code works on Pycharm (windows)
But it does not work on the AWS Linux machine. Any suggestions?
Nsepy library is not useful alternative as it provides only historical data.

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

q = nse.get_quote('infy')
print(q)
```

Update:
Tried following things...

1. Changed port on AWS EC2 to 80 ==> Does not work
2. Apparently NSE has blocked access to AWS based programs==> Any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: There are always ways to resolve such issues, but if the NSE has blocked AWS, then it may be illegal to access it from AWS, and I'm not sure if telling you how to do illegal things would be consistent with the Stackoverflow T&C's. If you can get their express written consent (which you'd need as part of their T&C's), they should be able to advise you on accessing it.